# Is 'home' a special hostname on Windows 7?

Tags: windows-7, networking, dns

My local network is managed by a router running [DD-WRT](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DD-WRT) which assigns a DNS hostname to each machine on the network that I've selected. For example, "laser" maps to a 192.168.1.7 (a laser printer) and "beagle" maps to a desktop server at 192.168.1.3.

I have a small [Raspberry Pi](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Raspberry_Pi) hosting a web server connected to this network at 192.168.1.11. The router assigns the DNS hostname "home" to this device. From Linux and Mac machines connected to this network, "home" resolves to 192.168.1.11 and http:// home/ brings up the web server. From a Windows 7 machine, I can access "laser", "beagle", etc. the same way, but not "home".

If I run:

```
> nslookup home
```

I get:

```
Server: DD-WRT
Address: 192.168.1.1

Name: home
Address: 192.168.1.11
```

This is correct and expected.

If I run:

```
> ping home
```

I get:

```
Ping request could not find host home. Please check the name and try again.
```

Requesting http:// home/ in a browser also fails.

Pinging other local hostnames work, requesting other local hostnames in a browser works.

This is a rather new install of Windows 7 as arrives on a Dell with very few changes made. `C:\WINDOWS\system32\drivers\etc\hosts` has not been modified, has no uncommented lines in it, and doesn't mention "home" anywhere, even in the comments.

The only explanation I can come up with is that "home" is some sort of special hostname in Windows 7. I couldn't find any reference to this online. Is this the case?

Comment: Does `ping demo.local` work? Also run `ipconfig` and look at the DNS-suffix of the main network adapter.

Comment: ping demo.local fails. This DNS-suffix of the main LAN adapter appears to be an empty string.

Comment: Sorry about my previous comment. I meant `ping home.local` of course. If that doesn't work could you try `ping -4 home` and `ping -4 home.local`?

Comment: No difference. All of these return "Ping request could not find host home.local. Please check the name and try again". Different hostnames, even with the -4 flag, same result. laser.local works fine.

Comment: Hm, I tried a couple more hostnames. A few (like laser) seem to work, others don't. It isn't just 'home', so 'home' isn't special. They all seem to work from other machines on the network. I don't see any obvious patterns in the hostnames or the ip addresses. It may not be a windows question after all, but I'm still stumped.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It may not be a [windows](/questions/tagged/windows)-specific question but it is definitively a [networking](/questions/tagged/networking) one :)

I did have this problem myself last year. I couldn't ping our demo-pc with `ping demo`. I also didn't have a DNS Suffix. But after adding it, the `ping demo.suffix` and the `ping demo` both started working.

There are 3 different things you could try (#1 being the preferred one):

---

## 1)

You can add a correct DNS Suffix to your network. I think this is the **preferred method** because it will correct this behavior on all machines without configuring them. You could use `my.lan` or something similar.

To set this up in a DD-WRT router you can follow this guide:
[How To Access Your Machines Using DNS Names with DD-WRT](http://www.howtogeek.com/69696/)

[image: DD-Wrt]

---

## 2)

Under the DNS tab of the advanced properties of the TCP/IPv4 of your network adapter you can under the "Append primary and connection specific DNS suffixes" **UNchecked** the box for "Append parent suffixes of the primary DNS suffix".

[image: DNS]

---

## 3)

If #2 does not work you can do the following:
Under the DNS tab of the advanced properties of the TCP/IPv4 of your network adapter you can change the radio button to "Append these DNS Suffixes (in order)" AND THEN click <kbd>Add</kbd> and for the suffix just enter a period `.`.

[image: DNS]